# Display all associated tags from content page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have found many similar questions, but not quite the right way around. I have a large number of tags that are associated with multiple content pages. When viewing these content pages you can only see the parent term, and not its children terms, which are equally as important. How can I display the entire list of terms, and not just the parent term in a content view?

Comment: Have you actually selected all the child terms for the page, or only the parent term?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using D7 then check this lovely module for displaying child terms after rendering. [Taxonomy display child terms](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display_child_terms).

You can look into [Taxonomy Display](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) module too.